# git pickaxe not finding modified line

Tags: git

Earlier today I was searching for the commit that changed a function name from `getReportHtml` to `getReport`.

I couldn't find it using the pickaxe, so I found it by manual searching.

Now that I know which commit had the change, I can see the change in my git diff output:

```
-               function getReportHtml(filters) {
+               function getReport(type, filters) {
```

I tried the following searches:

```
git log -SgetReportHtml
git log -SgetReportHtml --diff-filter=M
git log -GgetReportHtml
```

They found commits, but not the one that changed the name.

This is the relevant section of the git-log man page:

```
   -S<string>
       Look for differences that change the number of occurrences of the specified string (i.e. addition/deletion) in a file. Intended for the scripter's use.

       It is useful when you're looking for an exact block of code (like a struct), and want to know the history of that block since it first came into being: use the feature iteratively
       to feed the interesting block in the preimage back into -S, and keep going until you get the very first version of the block.

   -G<regex>
       Look for differences whose patch text contains added/removed lines that match <regex>.
```

The commit that introduced the change did change the number of occurrences of 'getReportHtml'. So why is it not found by the pickaxe?

Comment: Can you try a `git log --all -GgetReportHtml`? Also, what version of git are you using?