# `git log -G ...` then show the relevant changes

Tags: git

If I search for all changes which contain "foo" with `git log -G foo` I get a list of commits.

Now these commits can have a lot of changes which don't contain "foo".

Is there a way to show only the changes/diffs which contain "foo"?

I could help myself with a ugly shell script and "grep -A ... -B ..." but maybe there is an easier solution?

Third party tools are valid answers, too.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51596369/. Check if my answer there helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64616432/. [My Gist](https://gist.github.com/phil-blain/2a1cf81a0030001d33158e44a35ceda6) has a little bit better version of the script.

Answer (score 1):

The `-G <pattern>` option affects the output of the `-p`, `--name-only` and `--name-status` options, which will only show files whose diff contain `<pattern>`.

So `git log -G foo -p` already filters out irrelevant files.

The above command will show the complete diff for each file, however, so you will still need some external processing to isolate the chunks within the diff, and output only the chunks which contain `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the full outputs of these commits' diffs via a simple grep

```
git log -p -G foo | grep foo
```

It will only pick the lines with said string, though, without their original diff context.